# Finding the Fourier series of a sum

Tags: analysis, fourier-series

I have recently started to learn about Fourier series, which have been defined by the complex exponential. 
So a Fourier series is on the form: 
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_ne^{inx}$$

Where the Fourier coefficient $c_n$ is defined as: 
$$ c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(y)e^{-iny}dy$$

If I am suppose to find the Fourier series of the sum:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {\cos(nx)}{n!} $$

how am I suppose to do it with this definition? Hope somebody can give a hint or explain a method to find the Fourier series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $e^{it} = \cos(t)+i\sin(t)$.

We have, for $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
2\pi c_n
 & =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(ky)}{k!}e^{-iny}\, {\rm d}y \\
 & = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(ky)e^{-iny} \, {\rm d}y \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

But 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(ky)e^{-iny} \, {\rm d}y
 & = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(ky)(\cos(-ny)+i\sin(-ny)) \, {\rm d}y \\
 & = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(ky)\cos(-ny) \, {\rm d}y + i\overbrace{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(ky)\sin(-ny)\, {\rm d}y}^0 \\
 & = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(ky)\cos(-ny)\,{\rm d}y, \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
which is zero, if $k\ne|n|$, and $\pi$, otherwise.

Thus,
$2\pi c_n = \frac{\pi}{|n|!}$
and therefore
$c_n = \frac{1}{2(|n|!)}.$ (for $n\ne0$)

---

*Edit:* For the $c_0$ term, we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
2\pi c_0
 & = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(ky) \, {\rm d}y
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
and $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(ky)\, {\rm d}y$ equals $2\pi$, if $k=0$, and $0$, otherwise.
So $c_0 = 1$.

We conclude that the Fourier serie of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ky)}{k!}$ is
$$\frac12+\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{inx}}{2(|n|!)}.$$

---

Notice that $\frac{e^{i\cdot0\cdot x}}{2(0!)} = \frac12$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{inx}
 & = c_0+\sum_{n\ne0} c_n e^{inx} \\
 & = 1+\sum_{n\ne0}\frac{e^{inx}}{2(|n|!)} \\
 & = \frac12 + \frac{e^{i\cdot0\cdot x}}{2(0!)}+ \sum_{n\ne0}\frac{e^{inx}}{2(|n|!)} \\
 & = \frac12 + \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{inx}}{2(|n|!)}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: So the Fourier series of this sum would be: 
$\frac {1}{2(|n|!} \cdot e^{inx}$ but what about the $c_0$ term, shouldn't that be included as well?

Comment: @MadsJeppesen I've edited my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: It helps a lot, thank you! Just a minor question: if $c_0 = 1$ how do you get $\frac {1}{2}$ and is it possible to perform the same computation, but instead of having $2\pi c_n = ... $ just do it with $c_n = \frac {1}{2\pi} ... $

Comment: @MadsJeppesen It's just a nice/tricky way to write it. See my last edit.

Comment: Sorry, I have one last question: when you evaluate $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos(ky)$ and say that is is equal to $2\pi$ if $k=0$ how is that true? Because when I take the integral of $cos(ky)$ i get $\frac{sin(ky)}{k}$ which is undefined when $k=0$

Comment: $\cos(kx)=1$ if $k=0$, thus $\int\cos(kx)dx = \int dx = 2\pi$.

Answer (score 3):

Observe by definition, we have
\begin{align}
\cos(n x) = \frac{e^{inx}+e^{-inx}}{2}
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n!} = \frac{1}{2}+\sum^\infty_{k=-\infty} \frac{e^{ikx}}{2(|k|!)}.
\end{align}

Comment: When you have that 
$$ \sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n!} = \frac{1}{2}+\sum^\infty_{k=-\infty} \frac{e^{ikx}}{2(|k|!)} $$ 

To you simply use that $cos(nx) = \frac {e^{inx}+e^{-inx}}{2}$, and if this is the case, then how do you get $\frac {1}{2}$ outside of the sum?